# ¿De qué forma puedo mostrar el contenido de mi lista?

Tags: c#

Estoy empezando a usar C#, y quiero ver los elementos que están dentro de una lista.

Se me ocurrió hacerlo de ésta manera:

```
List<PedidoViewModel> lista = await SelectConexionMySql(consulta);

for (int i = 0; i < lista.Count; i++)
{
    Logger.Debug("Elemento de la lista: " + lista[i]);
}
```

Pero el Debug me muestra esto:

```
WebLogistica.Models.PedidoViewModel
```

¿Cómo puedo ver el contenido que se encuentra en cada posición?

Comment: Antes de jugar a los detectives y a las entrevistas, aquí una lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 luego de leer las recomendaciones, edita la pregunta y agrega todos los elementos necesarios para reproducir tu escenario. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que eres nuevo en C#, por lo cual me gustaría orientarte un poco.

---

Tienes una lista de objetos de tipo `PedidoViewModel`. Esto podemos descomponerlo en la lista y el objeto como tal.

**-El objeto:**

`PedidoViewModel` es un objeto, y debido a esto, tiene un método `ToString()` que por defecto devuelve el nombre completo de dicho objeto; esto es, el espacio de nombres + el nombre del tipo.

<sub>Esto es un espacio de nombres donde está contenido tu objeto:</sub>

```
WebLogistica.Models
```

<sub>Y esto, es tu objeto, que está en el espacio de nombres anterior:</sub>

```
PedidoViewModel
```

<sub>Si combinamos ambos, tenemos esto, que es lo que ves en tu consola de depuración:</sub>

```
WebLogistica.Models.PedidoViewModel
```

Ten en cuenta que puedes llamar a `ToString()` de forma explícita:

```
Logger.Debug(lista[i].ToString());
```

Y que al concatenar con una cadena, el compilador llama a `ToString()` de forma implícita:

```
Logger.Debug("" + lista[i]);
```

Por esto, estas dos líneas son equivalentes:

```
Logger.Debug("Elemento de la lista: " + lista[i]);
Logger.Debug("Elemento de la lista: " + lista[i].ToString());
```

Y obtienes:

```
Elemento de la lista: WebLogistica.Models.PedidoViewModel
```

Entonces, sabiendo esto, la forma correcta sería de la siguiente manera:

Si tu objeto `PedidoViewModel` presenta alguna propiedad que le identifique, como por ejemplo:

```
public class PedidoViewModel
{
    ...
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Entonces haces:

```
Logger.Debug("Elemento de la lista: " + lista[i].Nombre);
```

**-La lista:**

Si bien tu lista se puede indexar, también te permite iterar sobre ella, entonces puedes usar alguna de estas dos formas:

<sub>Acceso mediante indexación:</sub>

```
List<PedidoViewModel> lista = await SelectConexionMySql(consulta);

for (int i = 0; i < lista.Count; i++)
{
    Logger.Debug("Elemento de la lista: " + lista[i].Nombre);
}
```

<sub>Acceso mediante iteración:</sub>

```
List<PedidoViewModel> lista = await SelectConexionMySql(consulta);

foreach (PedidoViewModel elemento in lista)
{
    Logger.Debug("Elemento de la lista: " + elemento.Nombre);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Con los datos que hay en la pregunta, vamos jugando a las ciegas:

PedidoViewModel supongo que tiene las siguientes propiedades:

```
"NombreItem"
"Cantidad"
```

Aplicamos la propiedad "NombreItem"

```
List<PedidoViewModel> lista = await SelectConexionMySql(consulta);

for (int i = 0; i < lista.Count; i++)
{
    Logger.Debug("Elemento de la lista: " + lista[i].NombreItem);
}
```

Si tenemos una lista con:

```
lista[0].NombreItem = "Tonkotsu Ramen"
lista[0].Cantidad = 2
lista[1].NombreItem = "Tempura"
lista[1].Cantidad = 2
```

El resultado sería:

```
Elemento de la lista: Tonkotsu Ramen
Elemento de la lista: Tempura
```

Comment: oiga señor.. que alcanza con sobreescribir el metodo ToString!!!! y no contestar perguntas tan malas!

Comment: hahaha oiga, recuerdo que usted mismo dijo que subió de reputación respondiendo preguntas "pavas" :p

Comment: pavas si... duplicadas, no :p (las dos respuestas valen eh)...

Comment: hahahaha un abrazo hermano :D